# jQuery: Dequeue Specific Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got some borders that animate around thumbnails in on mouseenter and out on mouseleave. Say a user moves their mouse between two repeatedly, quickly enough that the animation doesn't have time to finish between before the user moves on. The result is that, even if the mouse isn't moving, the border bounces back and forth between the two images they switched between until all the queued animations finish, which can take a while. To prevent this, I've added a `.dequeue()` before the `.animate()`. This works well, except that I may have some other animations running. I don't want to stop/dequeue these.
 **Is there a way to selectively dequeue animations, excluding some?** The ones I want to exclude are scroll animations, also triggered on mouseenter.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427678/jquery-interrupt-animation

Comment: Not a duplicate. That thread is about general dequeuing.

Comment: IDEA! Is it possible to do this using multiple queues? So, I queue the border animations into one queue and the scrolls into another, and just stop the one I want to. Would that work? I've never quite got the hang of the `queue()` stuff, I'd love a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/L7ajF/2/)?

**EDIT**:
Ah I see, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/L7ajF/4/) is the closest solution that i can think of.

Comment: That's a general stop. I'm looking to stop *just the other border animations*.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this, I don't think you'll find an approach that doesn't involve re-writing a fair portion of the animation engine.  The animations take an object when queued.  It [loops though *all* properties in the object and determines the start value and end value](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L180-212).  To get the value at the step of the animation (depending on your easing, we'll use `linear` as an example here), it [multiplies that difference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L302) by [the percentage along the animation is](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/effects.js#L439).

It's all handled as a group of properties, you can't really split them off and stop the animation of some and not others...it just isn't built to be handled that way.  *If* it were, it's be a huge performance penalty to handle them separately (think about how many times this code runs)...so for such a rare case (your needs here), the library is going to choose the high-performance route that fits the other 99% of cases.